# Check which worksheets to export as pdf

Tags: vba, loops, checkbox, userform, export-to-pdf

I am a beginner in Excel VBA but I would like to create a file where I can select certain worksheets by means of a userform with checkboxes. In principle, it is then intended that only the check boxes where the value is true should be exported.

Below I have 2 codes that work well separately from each other but I have not yet been able to get them to work together.

Note: both codes come from the internet.

If possible I would like to write a loop to keep the overview.

the code to export sheets as pdf and put them in a outlook

```
Sub Saveaspdfandsend1()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim xArrShetts As Variant
Dim xPDFNameAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
xArrShetts = Array("test", "Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'Enter the sheet names you will send as pdf files enclosed with quotation marks and separate them with comma. Make sure there is no special characters such as \/:"*<>| in the file name.

For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
On Error Resume Next
Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
Exit Sub
End If
Next


Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
Exit Sub
End If
'Check if file already exist
xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))

xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & ".pdf"
xNum = 1
While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & xNum & ".pdf"
xNum = xNum + 1
Wend
Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
Else

End If
xArrShetts(I) = xStr
Next

'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
With xEmailObj
.Display
.To = ""
.CC = ""
.Subject = "????"
For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
.Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
Next
If DisplayEmail = False Then
'.Send
End If
End With
End Sub
```

the other code i tried I can see which checkbox is checked unfortunately I can't rewrite it so only the checked boxes will be exported to pdf.

```
Private Sub CommandButton100_Click()

For i = 100 To 113

If UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True Then
a = a + 1
End If

Next i

k = 1

For i = 100 To 113

If UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True And a = 1 Then
    b = UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Caption & "."
ElseIf UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True And k <> a Then
    b = b & UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Caption & ", "
    k = k + 1
ElseIf UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True And k = a Then
    b = b & "and " & UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Caption & "."
End If

Next i

MsgBox ("You have selected " & b)

End Sub
```

Can someone help me please I am struggling for some time now?

Comment: So, you practically needs to build `xArrShetts ` from the selected check boxes caption. Should this understanding be correct?

Comment: that's correct!

Comment: OK. I will post an answer...

Comment: Please, test the solution I suggested in my answer. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
  Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
  For Each c In uF.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
        End If
  Next
  sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")
End Function
```

It will return an array composed from the ticked check boxes caption.

It can be used demonstratively, in this way:

```
Sub testSheetsArrFunction()
    Debug.Print Join(sheetsArr(UserForm2), ",")
End Sub
```

The above code will return in Immediate Window a string containing the checked check boxes caption (separated by comma). It may be run from a standard module, too. Of course, the function must be copied in that module. And the form to be loaded, having some check boxes ticked.

Now, you have to change a single code line in your (working) code:

Replace:

```
xArrShetts = Array("test", "Sheet1", "Sheet2")
```

with:

```
xArrShetts = sheetsArr(UserForm2)
```

It should use the array built in the above function. **Of course** the function have to be copied in the module where to be called. If placed in the form code module, it can be simple called as:

```
xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me)
```

**Edited**:

You should only paste the next code in the form code module and show the form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo, I, xNum As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim xArrShetts As Variant
Dim xPDFNameAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
'xArrShetts = Array("test", "Sheet1", "Sheet2") 'Enter the sheet names you will send as pdf files enclosed with quotation marks and separate them with comma. Make sure there is no special characters such as \/:"*<>| in the file name.
xArrShetts = sheetsArr(Me)

For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    If xSht.Name <> xArrShetts(I) Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet no found, exit operation:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & xArrShetts(I), vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next


Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
    xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
'Check if file already exist
xYesorNo = MsgBox("If same name files exist in the destination folder, number suffix will be added to the file name automatically to distinguish the duplicates" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click Yes to continue, click No to cancel", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
If xYesorNo <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
    Set xSht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xArrShetts(I))
    
    xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & ".pdf"
    xNum = 1
    While Not (Dir(xStr, vbDirectory) = vbNullString)
        xStr = xFolder & "\" & xSht.Name & "_" & xNum & ".pdf"
        xNum = xNum + 1
    Wend
    Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
        xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xStr, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    End If
    xArrShetts(I) = xStr
Next

'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "????"
    For I = 0 To UBound(xArrShetts)
        .Attachments.Add xArrShetts(I)
    Next
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Function sheetsArr(uF As UserForm) As Variant
  Dim c As MSForms.Control, strCBX As String, arrSh
  For Each c In uF.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.Value = True Then strCBX = strCBX & "," & c.Caption
        End If
  Next
  sheetsArr = Split(Mid(strCBX, 2), ",") 'Mid(strCBX, 2) eliminates the first string character (",")
End Function
```

Comment: @Thom Haasert Didn't you find some time to check the above function? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: @faneduruI am going to test it now, i'll let you know

Comment: I can't get the file to work. I have a document with five different worksheets. the UserForm has been created but the formulas behind the nodes have not yet been created. Can I send you the file so you could put the formulas there I can look what I did wrong

Comment: @Thom Haasert What 'formula' are you referring to? You should only copy the above function to the form module code and replace a single code line, **as I recommended**... If it looks difficult, please share your workbook using a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one, easy to be used. Just let me know about that...

Comment: @Thom Haasert Still alive?

Comment: @Thom Haasert Did you share a workbook having a form without any code in its code module? I was expecting to see how you tried implementing the above solution. Do you want me to write the code?

Comment: i tried to put it in the module but didn't work so i cleared the module. the two codes i used you can find under modules in  visual basic

Comment: @Thom Haasert There is no any module in the workbook you sent. Anyhow, I will edit the above answer and place all the code you should copy in your form code module... I will do it copying the code I will place in your workbook form.

Comment: Please, download your workbook with the above code from [here](https://easyupload.io/o3n96i). If it works as you need, I would like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question, vote the answer up (pressing the left code side up arrow) and more important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar solution, will know that the code works...

Comment: your solution works thank  you very much, you helped me a lot.  is it also possible to export to pdf and make it fit on one page?

Comment: @Thom Haasert Probably, yes. You should play with the sheet PageSettup, as you try printing it (in code). If you place another question, putting the above code and asking for fitting on one sheet and tag me here, I will try helping you. If not available, somebody else will solve it, or me when more availability...